# AngularJS: Why am getting an "Error: [$injector:unpr]" error for a factory but not service?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, factory, minify

I have two blocks of code, one is a service and the other is a factory. Adhering the minification best practices, I have injected the dependencies as such:

Service

```
    lostPasswordServiceModule.service('servicemodule_lostpassword_service',
                ['$timeout',
                 '$scope', 
                 function ($timeout, $scope) {                      
            ...
     }]);
```

Factory (PROBLEM)

```
    lostPasswordServiceModule.factory('servicemodule_lostpassword_service',
                ['$timeout',
                 '$scope', 
                 function ($timeout, $scope) {                      
            ...
    }]);
```

However, for some reason beyond me I am getting an  "Error: [$injector:unpr]" error on the factory definition.

Now if I simply remove the minification parms from the factory injections and change it to:

```
    lostPasswordServiceModule.factory('servicemodule_lostpassword_service',
               [function ($timeout, $scope) {                           
           ...
    }]);
```

The error goes away and the world is happy.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong and why I'm unable to inject my factory dependencies with the extra minification args?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure about why the error is appearing, but can you explain why you are injecting `$scope` into a service/factory, as that might be your issue. Scopes are typically injected just into controllers (and referenced/used by directives)

Comment: I was evaluating different service types and was passing in dependencies randomly.  I removed, $scope from the factory and replaced it $http and the problem went away.  However, it doesn't explain why the service doesn't complain.  Good thinking though.

Comment: Try with return function ($timeout, $scope)